# MYSQL query on two different columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores id's, field names and field values. I need to search on two different fields, where the ID's are the same and the field values are taken from two columns using the BETWEEN compare.

Here is a sample of the table:

```
lid  |  field_name  | field_value
 1   |     lat      |  32.409172
 1   |     lng      | -90.13618300000002
 2   |     lat      |  38.409172
 2   |     lng      | -92.13618300000002
```

And so on. The idea is to get lid's where lat is between X and Y and lng is between A and B.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample output you're expecting?

Comment: You should probably think about changing your table schema if you are primarily going to be querying that table in that manner. I would think lat and long should be two fields. That would simply your query greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self-join to have latitude and longtitude in one row, then you can apply a `where` clause as you like:

```
SELECT lid, lat.field_value AS lat, lng.field_value AS lng
FROM table lat
INNER JOIN table lng
ON lat.lid = lng.lid AND lng.field_name = "lng"
WHERE (lat.field_value BETWEEN x AND y
OR lng.field_falue BETWEEN a AND b)
AND lat.field_name = "lat"
```

Comment: I am getting no results. I am looking to see if there results in the table, but there should be since the values I am inputting are sent from the map of listings.

Comment: Maybe you want `(lat.field_value BETWEEN x AND y OR lng.field_falue BETWEEN a AND b)` instead of the `and` constraint?

Comment: That is it! If you edit your response I will accept it!

Comment: @Judson Ok, I changed it accordingly.

Comment: An OR selects those entries which lie either inside of the north-south rectangle, or inside of the west-east rectangle. If you want all entries which are in both rectangles at the same time, then the AND was correct.

Comment: Maybe you should leave out those two constraints and look at the full result set. Then look at that what you are searching and think about which constraints make sense.

Comment: the AND returning no results was strange, because I have about 6 listings with the same lat/lng and they are within the outer limits of the coordinates. When I ran just the latitude search it had a lit of results whose ID's matched the longitude search results. But this helps a great deal. I will begin to test it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

here is all the LIDs with lng between 50 and 60 and lat between 70 and 80. I'm assuming your table is named "table"

```
select t1.lid
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.lid=t2.lid
where t1.field_name='lng'
and t1.field_value between 50 and 60 
and t2.field_name='lat'
and t2.field_value between 70 and 80
```